# Spectral Condition Number Bound

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-norms

In this [paper](https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/S0024379597800298?token=CE0B1173B33EB12B0964923E7EFCD108CDA5448EB19112314B8C3EA0D63EC91700253F797FDBAD97E6717334944AD5C0), the author says that if $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix and $P$ is the transformation such that $P^{-1}AP=J$ where $J=\text{diag}(\lambda_1,\lambda_2, \dots, \lambda_n)$. Then we can define $$G=\{P\mid P^{-1}AP=J\}.$$ Then we say that $\kappa(A)=\min_G||P||_2\ ||P^{-1}||_2$. is called the $\textit{Spectral Condition number of $A$}$

I haven't seen this definition before and I'm curious as to where they got it.

Comment: I infer you are using the operator 2 norm.  This is in effect taking advantage of submultiplicativity of said norm.  $\Big\Vert A\Big \Vert_2= \Big\Vert PD P^{-1}\Big \Vert_2\leq \Big\Vert P\Big \Vert_2 \Big \Vert D \Big \Vert_2 \Big \Vert P^{-1}\Big \Vert_2 = \max_i \vert \lambda_i \vert\cdot \Big\Vert P\Big \Vert_2 \Big \Vert P^{-1}\Big \Vert_2 $  and they want the tightest bound for the RHS.  Ideally your matrix is normal so $\kappa(A)=1$.